# Android GridView in a scroll view

Tags: android, gridview, scrollview

I have a layout which requires me to put a grid view inside a scroll view, i have read this is not suggested but my layout requires this.

When inserting a `GridView` in a `ScrollView` the grid does not scroll! I have got around this with the following.

The problem i have is that i have is the grid view will not scroll smoothly, if i hold my finger down and drag it scrolls, but if i do a swipe type of gesture it does not do a smooth scroll as expected. as soon as i remove my finger the scrolling stops on the grid view.

```
gridView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

     @Override
     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
     if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN
     || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
     gridView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

}
return false;

}

});
```

i tried adding this but no luck

```
gridView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view,
            int scrollState) { // TODO Auto-generated method
                                                // stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view,
                    int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount,
                        int totalItemCount) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    gridView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            }
        });
```

EDIT:

Just to give a bit more information

the grid view is inserted programatically, inside a relative layout which sits in a linear layout inside a scrollview

Comment: just add scrolview in your xml.. code is not necessary...

Comment: GridView itself provides scroll, why you want add another scroll, & add some top & bottom padding

Comment: the grid view is a small part of the template, there is a lot going on above and below the grid view which is why i have it in a scroll view

Comment: @RIT 3 ya but in question he mentioned scrolview. n i thought he need it..

Answer (score 0):

I would Suggest you to use [ExpandableHeightGridView](https://gist.github.com/sakurabird/6868765). It works for me very fine.Hope this will help you :)

Comment: show all the item, That was My need. Well It whould scroll also cause ExpandableHeightGridView extends GridView.. But I didn't try that... so not that sure :P

Comment: i need my grid view to have a fixed height with scrolling enabled, i don't think this will work for me.

Comment: did You give it a shot ??

Comment: i did not, but i reviewed the code of it, and the only thing it is doing is setting the height of the grid view which i don't need unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

To Answer my own question, i found a solution taking some parts from this example, works perfectly

https://github.com/Durgadass/ScrollInsideScroll